# How can dish-soap make glass less misty?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Warm glass that face a cold temperature becomes misty - but becomes less misty if sprayed with dish-soap. Moreover, dish-soap sprayed on glass makes the glass less misty, if it face a drastic change in temperature - at least makes it harder for the glass to become misty.

- Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fogging is caused by tiny droplets of water. These condense onto the glass when hot humid air comes in contact with a cold surface . The dish-soap acts as surfactant. The dish soap prevents droplets from forming. It forces any water molecules that condense onto the surface to be evenly spread across the surface. Thus, the water molecules form a thin film instead. This film is usually thin enough to not impede vision.